# How do GPT models go from token probabilities to textual outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gpt

Suppose GPT-2 or GPT-3 is trying to generate the next token, and it has a probability distribution (after applying softmax to some output logits) for the different possible next tokens. How does it choose what token to use in its textual output?

The [GPT-2 paper](https://d4mucfpksywv.cloudfront.net/better-language-models/language_models_are_unsupervised_multitask_learners.pdf) mentions top-k random sampling (citing "[Hierarchical Neural Story Generation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.04833.pdf)") and never mentions beam search. The [GPT-3 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.14165.pdf) mentions nucleus sampling (citing "[The Curious Case of Neural Text Degeneration](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09751.pdf)") and mentions beam search (citing "[Exploring the Limits of Transfer Learning with a Unified Text-to-Text Transformer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.10683.pdf)").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any language model can generate text with different approaches:

- **Greedy decoding**: you get the highest probability token at each time step.
- **Sampling**: the generated token is sampled from the probability distribution at each time step.
- **Temperature sampling**: the generated token is sampled from the probability distribution after applying a temperature factor $\alpha$, which can either flatten the distribution or sharpen it.
- **Beam search**: you keep the highest `k` most probable subsequences (i.e. the "beam"); when you finish decoding them, you output the most probable one.
- **Top-k sampling**: you sample from the probability distribution, but only considering the top `k` most probable tokens.
- **Nucleus sampling**: you sample from the probability distribution, but only consider the top probability tokens that add up to a specific cumulative probability `p`.

The OpenAI's API allows selecting the following approaches for both the [completions](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions) and the [chat](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat) endpoints:

- Temperature sampling, with the `temperature` parameter.
- Nucleus sampling, with the `top_p` parameter.

You can specify both of them, but OpenAI suggests you only use one of them at the same time.

If you want to know the specific detail of the implementation of these approaches, you can check [this post](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate) from the Huggingface blog.

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious which of these the GPT-2 and GPT-3 models actually use? I want to understand the algorithm in detail.

Comment: GPT-2 is not offered in the OpenAI API. If someone runs it, they decide what decoding strategy to use. As I commented in the answer, GPT-3 and GPT-4 support temperature sampling and nucleus sampling. There is not much detail to provide apart from the information I mentioned. What is not clear from it?

Comment: I have added a useful link about the details of the implementation of the different approaches. Please, consider upvoting and accepting the answer or, alternatively, let me know what is not clear from it.

Comment: I accepted the answer. It is strange that the [OpenAI Playground](https://platform.openai.com/playground) lets me set "Temperature" = 0 and "Top P" = 0.